# Is not possible install MySQL 8 on Fedora Workstation 39

Tags: fedora, software-installation, mysql, gpg

Through `VirtualBox` was installed `Fedora Workstation` **39**. Now I tried to install MySQL 8 server . I got the `mysql80-community-release-fc39-1.noarch.rpm` file from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ about the `MySQL Yum Repository` section

Well was executed

```
sudo rpm -Uvh mysql80-community-release-fc39-1.noarch.rpm 
warning: mysql80-community-release-fc39-1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3a79bd29: NOKEY
Verifying...                          ################################# [100%]
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:mysql80-community-release-fc39-1 ################################# [100%]
```

and

```
sudo dnf install mysql-community-server
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                                                                                                  310 kB/s | 209 kB     00:00    
MySQL Connectors Community                                                                                                   60 kB/s |  12 kB     00:00    
MySQL Tools Community                                                                                                        60 kB/s |  81 kB     00:01    
Dependencies resolved.
============================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                         Architecture            Version                                   Repository                          Size
============================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql-community-server                          x86_64                  8.0.35-10.fc39                            mysql80-community                   20 M
     replacing  mariadb-connector-c-config.noarch 3.3.5-2.fc39
Installing dependencies:
 mecab                                           x86_64                  0.996-5.fc39                              fedora                             356 k
 mysql-community-client                          x86_64                  8.0.35-10.fc39                            mysql80-community                  3.7 M
 mysql-community-client-plugins                  x86_64                  8.0.35-10.fc39                            mysql80-community                  1.3 M
 mysql-community-common                          x86_64                  8.0.35-10.fc39                            mysql80-community                  557 k
 mysql-community-icu-data-files                  x86_64                  8.0.35-10.fc39                            mysql80-community                  2.3 M
 mysql-community-libs                            x86_64                  8.0.35-10.fc39                            mysql80-community                  1.5 M
Installing weak dependencies:
 mecab-ipadic                                    x86_64                  2.7.0.20070801-28.fc39                    fedora                              10 M
 mecab-ipadic-EUCJP                              x86_64                  2.7.0.20070801-28.fc39                    fedora                             9.6 M

Transaction Summary
============================================================================================================================================================
Install  9 Packages

Total download size: 50 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/9): mecab-0.996-5.fc39.x86_64.rpm                                                                                        231 kB/s | 356 kB     00:01    
(2/9): mecab-ipadic-2.7.0.20070801-28.fc39.x86_64.rpm                                                                       3.7 MB/s |  10 MB     00:02    
(3/9): mysql-community-client-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm                                                                     2.3 MB/s | 3.7 MB     00:01    
(4/9): mysql-community-common-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm                                                                     2.7 MB/s | 557 kB     00:00    
(5/9): mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm                                                             1.8 MB/s | 1.3 MB     00:00    
(6/9): mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm                                                             3.8 MB/s | 2.3 MB     00:00    
(7/9): mysql-community-libs-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm                                                                       2.9 MB/s | 1.5 MB     00:00    
(8/9): mecab-ipadic-EUCJP-2.7.0.20070801-28.fc39.x86_64.rpm                                                                 2.2 MB/s | 9.6 MB     00:04    
(9/9): mysql-community-server-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm                                                                     8.1 MB/s |  20 MB     00:02    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                       6.8 MB/s |  50 MB     00:07     
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                                                                                                  3.0 MB/s | 3.1 kB     00:00    
Importing GPG key 0xA8D3785C:
 Userid     : "MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>"
 Fingerprint: BCA4 3417 C3B4 85DD 128E C6D4 B7B3 B788 A8D3 785C
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Key imported successfully
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                                                                                                  365 kB/s | 3.1 kB     00:00    
Importing GPG key 0x3A79BD29:
 Userid     : "MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>"
 Fingerprint: 859B E8D7 C586 F538 430B 19C2 467B 942D 3A79 BD29
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Is this ok [y/N]: y
error: Certificate 467B942D3A79BD29:
  The certificate is expired: The primary key is not live
Key import failed (code 2). Failing package is: mysql-community-client-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-common-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-common-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-libs-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-libs-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-server-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-server-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED
```

How to fix this situation?

Comment: have you researched the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the GPG key for the repo isn't valid because the certificate is expired for `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022`. It expired in October 2022.

For some reason, the latest that has been valid since November 2023 is seen as being not valid even though it was imported properly when you answered `y` during the command: `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023`

This appears to a be a bug. You can get around it by disabling the GPG check in `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo` by editing the line with `gpgcheck`  to say `0` under the first section of `[mysql80-community]` so that it looks like this

```
[mysql80-community]
name=MySQL 8.0 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/$releasever/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023
```

That will disable it until you set it back to `1` when the issue is fixed.

You can also just install the package with

```
dnf --nogpgcheck install mysql-community-server
```

However, that method will require that you update it separately with the `--nogpgcheck` switch every time.

That is only necessary if you insist on installing it from the `mysql-community` repo.

You can also just use the following to install it from the Fedora repo without adding that repo.:

```
dnf install community-mysql-server
```

That is the same major release with the same features and won't require anything regarding the GPG keys. Some of the config files may be different but there's nothing major.