# Fedora 39 - How to remove expired GPG key installed by MySQL?

Tags: fedora, mysql, gpg

I have the following situation

- [Is not possible install MySQL 8 on Fedora Workstation 39](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765518/is-not-possible-install-mysql-8-on-fedora-workstation-39)

Pls, see how was installed to understand this post. Anyway I am going in peace to wait until mysql itself resolves that bug.

Meanwhile when is executed `sudo dnd update` appears in somepoint

```
Total                                                                                                                       702 kB/s | 1.5 MB     00:02     
Delta RPMs reduced 237.9 MB of updates to 237.4 MB (0.2% saved)
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                                                                                                  349 kB/s | 3.1 kB     00:00    
GPG key at file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023 (0xA8D3785C) is already installed
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                                                                                                  3.0 MB/s | 3.1 kB     00:00    
Importing GPG key 0x3A79BD29:
 Userid     : "MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>"
 Fingerprint: 859B E8D7 C586 F538 430B 19C2 467B 942D 3A79 BD29
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

With either `y` or `N` the process fails. For example with `N` appears:

```
Is this ok [y/N]: n
Didn't install any keys
Public key for mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-common-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-common-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-libs-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-libs-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-server-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-server-8.0.35-10.fc39.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023, file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED
```

Just in case I tried with the `sudo dnf remove mysql-server mysql-client`  command but appears

```
No match for argument: mysql-server
No match for argument: mysql-client
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Therefore I am assuming the unique way to update Fedora is by removing that expired key for MySQL

- How to remove expired GPG key installed by MySQL?

My main goal is remove by complete everything about MySQL, in this case about the GPG key, to wait in peace the respective patch and right now let me do the OS update in peace.

Comment: Are you asking for a specific way to configure this via GPG or as setting in mysql? Because the file location is given in your output - which means you may just delete said file manually. Or better move/rename it and see what happens, so you can restore it if need be.

Comment: To resolve this specific situation - I think about the former about your question - and of course apply the correct and safe approach to accomplish my goal.